# How to determine line ending types in Ruby

Tags: ruby, line-endings

I am using [CSVLint](https://github.com/theodi/csvlint.rb) to run some validation on flat files. The sources for the files can have varied line endings, some are `\n`, some `\r\n`. The `Validator` constructor takes a `dialect` parameter where I need to specify the line ending type.

Is there a good/quick/easy way to sample the first line of the flat file to determine the line ending type in Ruby?

### Update

The answer below is the correct answer to my question.  If you need auto line endings in CSVLint, however, try this in the dialect:

```
"lineTerminator" => :auto
```

Also, @sawa's answer below pertains to my original question (and typo) of looking for `\r` and `\r\n`.

Comment: I suspect you have a typo in your post: The line endings in your files are likely to be `\n` and `\r\n`. `\r` on its own is not usually considered a line ending.

Comment: @Jordan good catch!  I was just reading about the old Mac line endings of `\r`! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect `\n` and `\r\n` line endings, simply match the first line against the regular expression `/\r?\n$/`:

```
def determine_line_ending(filename)
  File.open(filename, 'r') do |file|
    return file.readline[/\r?\n$/]
  end
end

determine_line_ending('./windows_file.csv')
# => "\r\n"

determine_line_ending('./unix_file.csv')
# => "\n"
```

This doesn't handle weird edge cases like the Mac OS 9 (discontinued in 2001) `\r` line ending, but covers everything else. If you want some background on historical line endings, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) is pretty interesting.

Comment: The OP explicitly describes some are `\r`, some are `\r\n`. You can capture `\n` or `\r\n` instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** The following is an answer to the original question, not the question after it has changed.

When you have the first line `line`,

```
line[/[\r\n]+/]
```

will give you what line ending you have.

Comment: you'd have to escape the slash right? so `/[\\r\\n]+/`

Comment: an efficient way to read the first line would be to use `file = File.open(your_file); first_line = file.gets`

Comment: @Anthony I flagged your first comment as not constructive.

Comment: sorry for not being constructive, but what am I missing here? http://rubular.com/r/lT5e9cPtKW

Comment: @Anthony: sawa's code is correct; those characters do not need to be escaped (unless you want to match a literal `\\`). However, s/he should not have flagged your comment, as you were obviously trying to be constructive.

Comment: @sawa I have flagged your most recent comment as not constructive. Also, your code will fail if the line contains an `\r` character that isn't followed by `\n`, e.g. `"foo\rbar\r\n"`.

Comment: @Jordan Doesn't `\r` count as a line end?

Comment: No, `\r` on its own is not a line ending. It's a [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return#Computers), which returns the cursor (or, in the case of printers "back in the day," the actual, physical carriage) to the beginning of the same line.

Comment: @Jordan But that is what the OP wanted to detect, isn't it? The OP explicitly describes some are `\r`, some are `\r\n`.

Comment: I believe that was a typo on OP's part. If OP has files with `\r` for line endings that would be very unusual. I've left a comment to that effect.

Comment: @Jordan That is a usual Mac file.

Comment: You're right—if you're using a Mac made before 2001. I would very much like to see your implementation of a method for detecting line endings for [every historical encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations).

Comment: @Jordan You don't need a Mac made before then. You need a file saved by a Mac made by then.

Comment: Yep. I made a safe assumption about the data OP is working with, which solved OP's immediate problem. You decided to make no such assumptions, which is fine and prudent, but your code, like mine, still fails for lines like `foo\nbar\r` when `\r` is the correct line ending. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Jordan In the OP's original description, OP wrote about the other two forms, but didn't write that there is an isolated `\n`, which implies that there is no such `\n`. That is what I assumed.

Comment: That's okay. We all make mistakes.

Comment: @Jordan Whose mistakes?